# swift scrollView subview width always 0?

Tags: swift, autolayout, scrollview

I met a strange problem, the subviews width is always 0 when I add it as subview of scrollView, but it works when I give the subview a specific number such as `make.width.equalTo(200)`.

I was wondering if it is because the scrollView cannot get the right width, but I check the hierarchy of screen it shows width is 393. Why the subviews suddenly cannot get right width.

Here is my demo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    private lazy var viewOne: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var viewTwo: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.alpha = 0.5
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var viewThree: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.alpha = 0.5
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        setupUI()
    }
    

    private func setupUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(viewOne)
        viewOne.backgroundColor = .blue
        scrollView.addSubview(viewTwo)
        scrollView.addSubview(viewThree)
        
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        viewOne.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
        
        viewTwo.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(viewOne.snp.bottom).offset(12)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
        
        viewThree.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(viewTwo.snp.bottom).offset(12)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(200)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `iOS 11`, a `UIScrollView` has 3 "frames" ...

- the view `.frame` itself
- the `.contentLayoutGuide`
- the `.frameLayoutGuide`

This was done because constraining subviews to the scroll view was ambiguous.

Constraints to the `.contentLayoutGuide` control the actual `.contentSize`. So, if you constrain a subview leading and trailing to the `.contentLayoutGuide`, and give that subview a `width: 2000`, the scroll view will scroll 2000-points horizontally.

If you want to size your subview(s) ***relative to the size of the scroll view's frame***, make use of the `.frameLayoutGuide`.

Take a look at the changes here:

```
private func setupUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(viewOne)
    viewOne.backgroundColor = .blue
    scrollView.addSubview(viewTwo)
    scrollView.addSubview(viewThree)
    
    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    viewOne.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalTo(scrollView.contentLayoutGuide)
        make.left.right.equalTo(scrollView.contentLayoutGuide)
        make.height.equalTo(200)
        // width equal to scrollView's frameLayoutGuide width
        make.width.equalTo(scrollView.frameLayoutGuide)
    }
    
    viewTwo.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalTo(viewOne.snp.bottom).offset(12)
        make.left.right.equalTo(scrollView.contentLayoutGuide)
        make.height.equalTo(200)
        // width equal to scrollView's frameLayoutGuide width
        make.width.equalTo(scrollView.frameLayoutGuide)
    }
    
    viewThree.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalTo(viewTwo.snp.bottom).offset(12)
        make.left.right.equalTo(scrollView.contentLayoutGuide)
        make.height.equalTo(200)
        make.bottom.equalTo(scrollView.contentLayoutGuide)
        // width equal to scrollView's frameLayoutGuide width
        make.width.equalTo(scrollView.frameLayoutGuide)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, appreciate. In fact, I used scrollview in a wrong way the whole time.. (But it always works, it's really wired when I using AutoLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to get the width early in your lifecycle, your subview has a zero width because it has no frame associated with it, given you're using SnapKit/AutoLayout.

Calling `subview.layoutSubviews()` before attempting to access its size will help here, however be cautious of calling this function too frequently as it does execute on the main thread.

Comment: I tried this before and after set width to scrollView's subviews but it didn't work. This is really strange because I always set layout like this but nothing wrong happen.